# Hadoop conf files missing

Tags: java, hadoop, jjaql

i am using hadoop through a Vm Image on RHEL 5 provided by Ibm BigInsights , i am unable to locate the conf folder . I want to embedd jaql with eclipse to develop a front end.

Answer (score 0):

In IBM Biginsights hadoop distribution, hadoop libraries, conf, scripts etc. are located under `/opt/ibm/biginsights/` directory by default. You can locate the configuration directory of each components by using the following find command

```
find /opt/ibm -iname "*-site.xml"
```